# How to add a map widget to a Lead object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads, page-layout

I saw this app that adds a map to the Lead object:
[image]

How can I do something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supporting [@Adrian's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) comment, I am providing my answer.

Rather than using "Google Maps API" (which is not fully **FREE**), I have used `<apex:map>` component which is in-build in Salesforce and takes the salesforce data.

**We do not need to call any other external api to pass the data.**

It has following features:

> Display an interactive, JavaScript-based map, complete with zooming, panning, and markers based on your Salesforce or other data.
>
> `<apex:map>` doesn't, by itself, display map markers, even for the center point. To display up to 100 markers, add child  components.

```
    <apex:map width="500px" height="175px" zoomLevel="15" mapType="roadmap" 
                                    center="{!accountObj.ShippingStreet},{!accountObj.ShippingCity},{!accountObj.ShippingState}">
      <apex:mapMarker title="{!accountObj.Name}" 
                                position="{!accountObj.ShippingStreet},{!accountObj.ShippingCity},{!accountObj.ShippingState}"/>
   </apex:map>
```

For more information refer [apex:map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm)

If you want to create lightning component using map then refer [Creating Account Map Component](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/project/account-geolocation-app/lc-app-06) in the trailhead.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty broad, but to point you in the right direction you'd need to add a Visualforce Component to the Page Layout of the record.

The Visualforce Page itself would need to use a standard controller so you could access relevant address fields of the Lead, then use [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) to display and show the map on the page which you could probably do using JavaScript, passing in the address of the record you're on to the API and getting it's location returned.

Comment: Or the `<apex:map>` component, which can geocode up to ten markers.